# why Sitecore Fast query is not working with items?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

Fast Query is only working with Database but not with Items.

this is working:-

```
Syntax: Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems("fast://*[@@templatename='Course Description']");
```

this is not working:-

```
Syntax:Sitecore.context.Item.Axes.SelectItems("fast://*[@@templatename='Course Description']");
```

I am getting this error: End of string expected at position 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. From the Using Sitecore Fast Query documentation at: http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/developer/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query/using%20sitecore%20fast%20query.pdf

Sitecore Fast Query can be used:

- In the Content Editor as a source for List Type fields.
- In the Developer Center, in the XPath Builder tab.
- In custom .NET code by using the SelectSingleItem() method and the SelectItems() methods of the Sitecore.Data.Database class.